# 100% width with fixed margin

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

http://jsbin.com/manez/1/

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: black;
    color:white;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

I'd like a DIV to be `width:100%` yet have a left margin of 50px, but without pushing the div 50px on the other end and enabling horizontal scrolling.

I understand this would be possible using jQuery:

`$('#container').width( $(window).width() - 50 );`

but I'm after a CSS only solution, if possible.

Comment: `width : calc(100% - 50px)` - Could use this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mixorido/1/), more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: @Ruddy HOLYC!! I didn't even know it existed. Please put it an answer. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both divs are absolute then do not use width. Use `left:50px` & `right:0` on container div. Div get width accordingly.

Comment: THANKS HEAPS!! ;) Accepting the answer after the acceptance limit expires

Comment: Although the other answers are equally AWESOME, but yours is better for some older browsers too.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
width : calc(100% - 50px) !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

So there is indeed such thing as: `width : calc(100% - 50px)`. I would recommending reading up on it first (limited browser support).

So we can use it like so:

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    width : calc(100% - 50px)
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsbin.com/mixorido/1/)

Also more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)